# php automation for some tasks

Tags: php, automation, task

i must call a php function every second

if i place it in a php file it runs a few times every call php file when calling an user

index.php

```
//code that i want run everysecond (or a few second)
 $bitsqlz = "SELECT id FROM tasks where id ='$todoid' and state='0';";
            $dataz = mysqli_query($con1,$bitsqlz); 
            while ($rowz= $dataz->fetch_assoc()) {
              $todoid= $rowz["id"];

//dont know how  but many users can come here even i set state = 0 below before all codes
// and same task runs a few times

$dataupd = mysqli_query($con1,"update todos set state=1 where id='$todoid'"); 

// proecess bla  bla bla...

}
```

or must i call it in server side ? (i dont know what is right way and how to make it runs in server side maybe linux can have a program for this. like schuled tasks. )

Comment: Linux has `cron`, but it's limited to, at most, once per minute. What are you you trying to do that requires such frequent updates?

Comment: it's a web based game and i want to achieve which war it's time. for example 10:07:23 war time. that code must work. but so many peeople calling index.php and code works a few times (not always but often)

Comment: Well, your code here doesn't seem to make any sense, but that aside, perhaps you should look at [Web Sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an infinite while whith an sleep() of 1 second. But remember to increase the set_time_limit() and use "break" to end the loop.

And if you need to execute a PHP script from the server site on Linux, you can execute it typing "php index.php".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).